# The simple present tense form of Willing to do

Tags: past-tense, progressive-aspect, periphrastic-modals

We use the phrase *be willing to do* in everyday English. But my problem is
how to use it in its simple present tense form with *-ing*.

For example, what is the simple
present tense form of this sentence?

> He is not willing to give any information.

Comment: How would "simple present tense" differ from the present tense that the sentence is in already?

Comment: Note that _willing_ is an adjective here, not a verb. So it doesn't have a simple present form. It is not the present participle of the verb _to will_ as in, e.g., _He is willing his team to win._

Comment: Are you looking for a one-word verb like the Latin *nolo*? "Nolo revelare ullam notitiam" or something? Even in Latin the third-person singular is "Non vult". While English has the verb *want,* it doesn't have one for *does not want,* because negation is easy with the "does not".

Comment: @AndrewLeach We used to have such a verb with the negation built in, but it survives only in frozen form such as the expression *will he or nill he* meaning whether he wants to or not.

Answer (score 2):

You are misreading the sequence of copula + adjective *am willing* as a progressive verb form: it is not. As others have said in the comments, *willing* is an adjective, so this is already present simple.

I cannot think of a verb that has the same meaning as *be willing*: it describes a mental state very different from *want*. These sentences are perfectly cromulent:

> I don't really want to talk to him, but I'm willing to do so if you think it will help.

> I want that car, but I'm not willing to pay that much for it.

Comment: The verb that means _be willing_ is the deontic sense of _will_, as in _If he will hand in his homework, I'm willing to correct it._

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. I was thinking it was only available in conditionals, but it could be used in either of my examples, with suitable emphasis on it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Interesting how to get the deontic/epistemic swap here with simple *will*, it looks like you need the progressive aspect. That is, *He won’t give any info* probably means only that he refuses (denies permission) to  do so right now and isn't trying to be predictive, whereas *He won't be giving any info* is almost always a prediction about the future not some command.

Comment: There's all kinds of idiomatic dodges like that with modals that swap deontic for epistemic, or reverse negation, like _must not_ versus _don't have to_. English modals are evolving very fast.

Comment: It seems to me that all these uses are deontic: epistemic _will_ is surely when we use it to express our conclusions, eg "He will have got there by now".